# Electron Method Callback

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm new to electron and trying to build an application to control smarthome-components from my Mac. To do this, I need many `HTTP-Request` so the idea is to make an own method/function for this job.
Now my problem is, that I don't know how to use this callback-thing ;)

This is my code now:

```
const {app, Tray, Menu, BrowserWindow, net} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'icon.png');
let appIcon = null;
let win = null;
var http = require('http');


function httpGet(url, callback) {
  http.get(url, (res) => {
    const { statusCode } = res;
    const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let rawData = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
    res.on('end', () => {
      return callback(rawData);
    });
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
  });
}


app.on('ready', function(){
  win = new BrowserWindow({show: false});
  appIcon = new Tray(iconPath);
  var contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'http',
      click: function() {
      console.log(httpGet('http://192.168.178.10/switches/status_1'),
        function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        }
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  appIcon.setToolTip('This is my application.');
  appIcon.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
});
```

Trey works, but the `httpGet` function does not return anything `(undefined [function])` and electron crashes.

Would be really thankful if someone could help me with this.

Greetings,
Lukas

Answer (score 0):

Bad news is that I do not know electron, so the TL;DR for the text below is as simple as: put a `console.log` line into the callback passed to `http.get`.

---

There is no return value in `httpGet` (and it is normal), that is why you can not log it. JavaScript event handling works with callbacks, and getting data via HTTP is an event.

What you have as second argument for `http.get` is the event handler.

While now it appears as a fancy lambda,

```
(res)=>{...}
```

in oldschool way it would look like

```
function(res){...}
```

So that is a function, and it will get invoked when something happens to the HTTP request you have issued, and that is where you could log/dig into the result (res).

What you see in your log at the moment:

- `undefined` is the return value of a function which does not return anything, `httpGet`
- `[function]` is the function you pass as second argument for `console.log`

```js
function a(){} // a function which does not return anything
console.log(a(),a); // logs function result and function itself
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the callback pattern is usually to write a function that accepts 2 parameters: `err` and `result`. If there was no error `err` becomes `null`, if there was an error `result` becomes `null`. So this would be the best way to write `httpGet`:

```
function httpGet(url, callback) {
  http.get(url, (res) => {
    const {
      statusCode
    } = res;
    const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let rawData = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      rawData += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      return callback(null, rawData);
    });
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
    return callback(e, null)
  });
}
```

Second, the way you wrote your call to `httpGet` is wrong. Change this:

```
console.log(httpGet('http://192.168.178.10/switches/status_1'),
  function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
);
```

To

```
httpGet('http://192.168.178.10/switches/status_1', function(err, rawData) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('httpGet failed!');
  } else {
    console.log(rawData)
  }
});
```